# How unpacking strict fields goes together with polymorphism?

Tags: optimization, haskell, ghc, strict, algebraic-data-types

The `{-# UNPACK #-}` pragma tells the compiler to eliminate redundant constructors. Quoting [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Data_types#Unpacking_strict_fields):

> For example, given this:
>
> ```
> data T = T {-# UNPACK #-} !(Int,Float)
> ```
>
> GHC will represent the type T like this:
>
> ```
> data T = T Int Float
> ```
>
> eliminating the tuple. This is commonly used to put unboxed Ints directly in a constructor:
>
> ```
> data T = T {-# UNPACK #-} !Int
> ```
>
> will be represented as
>
> ```
> data T = T Int#
> ```

I was wondering, **does this also work when the field to be unpacked is polymorphic?** For example, if I define

```
data S' a   = S String {-# UNPACK #-} !a

type S1     = S' Int
newtype S2  = S2 (S' Int)
```

will functions that work with `S1` or `S2` be optimized?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting from Don's [blog](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/self-optimizing-data-structures-using-types-to-make-lists-faster/) about unpacking

> It does not make sense for polymorphic fields, since they have variable size, and the compiler does not (except in very specific circumstances) have access to information about what types are in use.

Also you can read Tibell's [reply](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/13234) to mailing list.

> Unfortunately unpacking doesn't work for polymorphic fields (the new warning for ineffective unpack pragmas in GHC head should warn about this) ...